# Vector refilling is slower than creating a new one?

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I was trying to implement an optimizer using Simplex Algorithm. The original codes online creates a new vector with 0 initial values in each iteration. I tried to create a common outside the loops, then use `std::fill` to reset the values in each iteration. I was surprised that the first one is faster than the second. To my view of point, the declaration, in any way, needs to ask for memory AND initialize the values, cannot be faster.

Could anyone help to explain this? If this is true, is there any disadvantage of the first approach? Or can we improve it further?

Here is the code.

New one:

```
    void Simplex(std::vector<double>& result, std::function<double(std::vector<double>)> func,
        std::vector<double> init, std::vector<std::vector<double>> x = std::vector<std::vector<double>>(),
        double EPS = 1E8 * std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon(), int MAXIT = 1000000)
    {
        int N = init.size();                                //  Space Dimension
        //  Coefficients for the new points.
        const double a = 1.0;       //  a: Reflection
        const double b = 1.0;       //  b: Expansion
        const double g = 0.5;       //  g: Contraction
        const double h = 0.5;       //  h: Multi-Contraction
        std::vector<double> xcentroid_old(N, 0);    //  Old Simplex Centroid * (N + 1)
        std::vector<double> xcentroid_new(N, 0);    //  New Simplex Centroid * (N + 1)
        std::vector<double> vf(N + 1, 0);           //  Values at Simplex Vertexes       
        int x1 = 0;                 //  Index of smallest vertex.
        int xn = 0;                 //  Index of second greatest vertex.
        int xnp1 = 0;               //  Index of greatest vertex.
        int countIT = 0;                //  Iteration Count

        //  If no initial simplex is specified, construct the trial simplex.
        if (x.size() == 0)
        {
            std::vector<double> del(init);
            //  del = init / 20
            std::transform(del.begin(), del.end(), del.begin(),
                std::bind2nd(std::divides<double>(), 20));
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                std::vector<double> tmp(init);
                tmp[i] += del[i];
                x.push_back(tmp);
            }
            x.push_back(init);

            // Calculate the xcentriod.
            std::transform(init.begin(), init.end(), xcentroid_old.begin(),
                std::bind2nd(std::multiplies<double>(), N + 1));
        }

        std::vector<double> xg(N);
        std::vector<double> xr(N);
        std::vector<double> xe(N);
        std::vector<double> xc(N);
        //  Optimization starts.
        for (countIT = 0; countIT < MAXIT; countIT++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < N + 1; i++)
                vf[i] = func(x[i]);

            // Find index of max, second max, min of vf.
            x1 = 0; xn = 0; xnp1 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < vf.size(); i++)
            {
                if (vf[i] < vf[x1])
                    x1 = i;
                if (vf[i] > vf[xnp1])
                    xnp1 = i;
            }
            xn = x1;
            for (int i = 0; i < vf.size(); i++)
            {
                if (vf[i] < vf[xnp1] && vf[i] > vf[xn])
                    xn = i;
            }

            //  xg: Centroid of the N best vertexes.
            std::fill(xg.begin(), xg.end(), 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
            {
                if (i != xnp1)
                    std::transform(xg.begin(), xg.end(), x[i].begin(), xg.begin(), std::plus<double>());
            }
            std::transform(xg.begin(), xg.end(),
                x[xnp1].begin(), xcentroid_new.begin(), std::plus<double>());
            std::transform(xg.begin(), xg.end(), xg.begin(),
                std::bind2nd(std::divides<double>(), N));

            //  Termination condition: change (sum of absolute differences on all dimensions)
            //  of simplex centroid is less than EPS.
            double diff = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                diff += fabs(xcentroid_old[i] - xcentroid_new[i]);
            if (diff / N < EPS)
                break;
            else
                xcentroid_old.swap(xcentroid_new);

            //  Reflection
            std::fill(xr.begin(), xr.end(), 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                xr[i] = xg[i] + a * (xg[i] - x[xnp1][i]);
            double fxr = func(xr);
            if (vf[x1] <= fxr && fxr <= vf[xn])
                //  If f(x1) <= f(xr) <= f(xn), update xnp1 to xr.
                std::copy(xr.begin(), xr.end(), x[xnp1].begin());
            else if (fxr < vf[x1])
            {
                //  If f(xr) < f(x1), expansion.
                std::fill(xe.begin(), xe.end(), 0);
                for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
                    xe[i] = xr[i] + b * (xr[i] - xg[i]);
                //  Update xnp1 to the better one of xr or xe.
                if (func(xe) < fxr)
                    std::copy(xe.begin(), xe.end(), x[xnp1].begin());
                else
                    std::copy(xr.begin(), xr.end(), x[xnp1].begin());
            }
            else if (fxr > vf[xn])
            {
                //  If f(xr) > f(xn), contraction.
                std::fill(xc.begin(), xc.end(), 0);
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                    xc[i] = xg[i] + g * (x[xnp1][i] - xg[i]);
                if (func(xc) < vf[xnp1])
                    //  If f(xc) < f(xnp1), update xnp1 to xc.
                    std::copy(xc.begin(), xc.end(), x[xnp1].begin());
                else
                {
                    //  If f(xc) >= f(xnp1), multi-contraction.
                    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if (i != x1)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                                x[i][j] = x[x1][j] + h * (x[i][j] - x[x1][j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (countIT == MAXIT)
            throw std::invalid_argument("Iteration limit achieves, result may not be optimal.");

        result = x[x1];
    }
```

Original one:

```
    void Simplex_Original(std::vector<double>& result, std::function<double(std::vector<double>)> func,
        std::vector<double> init, std::vector<std::vector<double>> x = std::vector<std::vector<double>>(),
        double EPS = 1E8 * std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon(), int MAXIT = 1000000)
    {
        int N = init.size();                                //  Space Dimension
        //  Coefficients for the new points.
        const double a = 1.0;       //  a: Reflection
        const double b = 1.0;       //  b: Expansion
        const double g = 0.5;       //  g: Contraction
        const double h = 0.5;       //  h: Multi-Contraction
        std::vector<double> xcentroid_old(N, 0);    //  Old Simplex Centroid * (N + 1)
        std::vector<double> xcentroid_new(N, 0);    //  New Simplex Centroid * (N + 1)
        std::vector<double> vf(N + 1, 0);           //  Values at Simplex Vertexes       
        int x1 = 0;                 //  Index of smallest vertex.
        int xn = 0;                 //  Index of second greatest vertex.
        int xnp1 = 0;               //  Index of greatest vertex.
        int countIT = 0;                //  Iteration Count

        //  If no initial simplex is specified, construct the trial simplex.
        if (x.size() == 0)
        {
            std::vector<double> del(init);
            //  del = init / 20
            std::transform(del.begin(), del.end(), del.begin(),
                std::bind2nd(std::divides<double>(), 20));
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                std::vector<double> tmp(init);
                tmp[i] += del[i];
                x.push_back(tmp);
            }
            x.push_back(init);

            // Calculate the xcentriod.
            std::transform(init.begin(), init.end(), xcentroid_old.begin(),
                std::bind2nd(std::multiplies<double>(), N + 1));
        }

        //  Optimization starts.
        for (countIT = 0; countIT < MAXIT; countIT++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < N + 1; i++)
                vf[i] = func(x[i]);

            // Find index of max, second max, min of vf.
            x1 = 0; xn = 0; xnp1 = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < vf.size(); i++)
            {
                if (vf[i] < vf[x1])
                    x1 = i;
                if (vf[i] > vf[xnp1])
                    xnp1 = i;
            }
            xn = x1;
            for (int i = 0; i < vf.size(); i++)
            {
                if (vf[i] < vf[xnp1] && vf[i] > vf[xn])
                    xn = i;
            }

            //  xg: Centroid of the N best vertexes.
            std::vector<double> xg(N, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
            {
                if (i != xnp1)
                    std::transform(xg.begin(), xg.end(), x[i].begin(), xg.begin(), std::plus<double>());
            }
            std::transform(xg.begin(), xg.end(),
                x[xnp1].begin(), xcentroid_new.begin(), std::plus<double>());
            std::transform(xg.begin(), xg.end(), xg.begin(),
                std::bind2nd(std::divides<double>(), N));

            //  Termination condition: change (sum of absolute differences on all dimensions)
            //  of simplex centroid is less than EPS.
            double diff = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                diff += fabs(xcentroid_old[i] - xcentroid_new[i]);
            if (diff / N < EPS)
                break;
            else
                xcentroid_old.swap(xcentroid_new);

            //  Reflection
            std::vector<double> xr(N, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                xr[i] = xg[i] + a * (xg[i] - x[xnp1][i]);
            double fxr = func(xr);
            if (vf[x1] <= fxr && fxr <= vf[xn])
                //  If f(x1) <= f(xr) <= f(xn), update xnp1 to xr.
                std::copy(xr.begin(), xr.end(), x[xnp1].begin());
            else if (fxr < vf[x1])
            {
                //  If f(xr) < f(x1), expansion.
                std::vector<double> xe(N, 0);
                for (int i = 0; i<N; i++)
                    xe[i] = xr[i] + b * (xr[i] - xg[i]);
                //  Update xnp1 to the better one of xr or xe.
                if (func(xe) < fxr)
                    std::copy(xe.begin(), xe.end(), x[xnp1].begin());
                else
                    std::copy(xr.begin(), xr.end(), x[xnp1].begin());
            }
            else if (fxr > vf[xn])
            {
                //  If f(xr) > f(xn), contraction.
                std::vector<double> xc(N, 0);
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                    xc[i] = xg[i] + g * (x[xnp1][i] - xg[i]);
                if (func(xc) < vf[xnp1])
                    //  If f(xc) < f(xnp1), update xnp1 to xc.
                    std::copy(xc.begin(), xc.end(), x[xnp1].begin());
                else
                {
                    //  If f(xc) >= f(xnp1), multi-contraction.
                    for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); i++)
                    {
                        if (i != x1)
                        {
                            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
                                x[i][j] = x[x1][j] + h * (x[i][j] - x[x1][j]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (countIT == MAXIT)
            throw std::invalid_argument("Iteration limit achieves, result may not be optimal.");

        result = x[x1];
    }
```

Test function:

```
double func(vector<double> x)
{
    return (x[0] * x[0] + x[1] * x[1]) * (x[0] * x[0] + x[1] * x[1]) - (x[0] - 3 * x[1]) * (x[0] - 3 * x[1]);
}

void main()
{
    int m = 1000, n = 10;
    double dz = 0.1 / m / n;
    vector<double> init(2), result(2);

    init[0] = 3;    init[1] = 3;
    clock_t t1;
    t1 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            init[0] += dz;
            Optimizer::Simplex_Original(result, func, init);
        }
    }
    cout << "Old:" << '\t' << float(clock() - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    cout << result[0] << '\t' << result[1] << endl;

    init[0] = 3;    init[1] = 3;
    t1 = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            init[0] += dz;
            Optimizer::Simplex(result, func, init);
        }
    }
    cout << "New:" << '\t' << float(clock() - t1) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
    cout << result[0] << '\t' << result[1] << endl;
}
```

I use VS 2013 with Release mode, O2 is turned on.

For the original one, 10000 repeats cost about 9s, but 13s for the new one.

Comment: please show the code, it is rather unclear what to explain. Of course not creating a new vector is faster than creating a new one

Comment: How much faster it is?

Comment: *I was surprised that the first one is faster than the second.* -- Please specify compiler and build settings you used.  If optimizations are not on, then your observations are meaningless.  Also, by what means are you timing your code?  You just state "this is slower/faster", but we have no metrics, no indication what you used, no code sample showing clock functions, nothing.

Comment: Can you post enough of the code that we can reproduce the behavior on our own systems? Curious to see what’s going on here.

Comment: Please make it an [mcve] including your timing results and also compiler flags

Comment: Thats not an minimal-cve, anyhow you still dont tell us how you measured the time and what are the results

Comment: btw its rather hard to check what are the differences between the two. Not only for here, but also for you, you should put everything that is same inside a function and call that

Comment: @tobi303 It is hard for me to put all the other parts in a function because I only updates the old one little by little. The only changes between the two functions is that I draw all the creation of vectors out of the loops.

Comment: your test is wrong. You can't test 2 methods like that. The first influences the second. You need to (ideally) test them separately  or make sure invalidate the cache between them.

Comment: @bolov Yes, you might be right. I will check again.

Comment: I tried to run your code, but it doesnt compile. Most errors I could fix, but you are calling the functions with 3 params when they expect 6.....

Comment: @tobi303 Sorry, I missed the default arguments. Please see the modified one.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine the vector constructor, knowing that the memory is contiguous, will be able to better optimise setting its contents. It can probably just memset the whole area, or something similar, whereas std::fill does not know what type of container it is accessing, so must iterate over all the elements by incrementing the iterator for every one and writing every one individually...

Comment: thats quite some speculations, do you have anything to back it up?

Comment: but std::fill does know the iterator type; in fact, clang's std::fill calls memset when appropriate

Answer (score 0):

Small changes to large complex functions can trigger all sorts of surprising performance changes (good or bad) in optimized code.  Processors are complicated and it can be very hard to predict what will be faster or slower.

That said, it's possible that allocating zero-filled memory is faster than setting an already-allocated block to zero.

Consider:

```
std::vector<double> xg(N, 0);
```

If `0.0` is represented with all-bits zero on your platform (likely), then this boils down to allocating a block of memory that's filled with zeros.  It turns out that most virtual memory operating systems make it easy to allocate memory that's already zeroed out.  In fact, the OS likely has a thread running on another core whose sole purpose is to zero-out unused blocks of memory so that they are available.  When the memory is allocated, it's already a bunch of zeros, so there's no additional work to do in the allocator.

Compare to:

```
std::fill(xg.begin(), xg.end(), 0);
```

That's using your thread on your core to zero out the chunk of memory.  You've effectively lost the concurrency of having the OS do this work for you, ahead of time, on its own thread.

While there is a performance cost to allocation, and you should generally consider it as a potential bottleneck if you're doing it a lot, you can't really know until you measure.